# iPhone 7 Plus not appearing on Airdrop

Tags: ios, airdrop, iphone

So I just got myself a new iPhone 7 Plus and I am having some issues with Airdrop. While I can send files to other devices just fine, the other devices cannot see my iPhone. Airdrop is turned on for Everyone and I already tried rebooting the device. Maybe there's some other setting that I am missing?

Comment: Is bluetooth and Wifi turned on as you're doing this?

Comment: Yes, and Airdrop is sending files just fine. The problem is when I try to send files from other devices to my iPhone.

Comment: If you can't see the person or the device that you're trying to AirDrop to, check the following:
• Check that both of you have Wi-Fi and Bluetooth turned on. If either of you have Personal Hotspot on, turn it off.
• Make sure that the person you're sending to is nearby. You can't AirDrop to users who are out of Bluetooth and Wi-Fi range.
• If the other person’s AirDrop receiving setting is set to Contacts Only, and you’re not in their Contacts, have them set their AirDrop receiving setting to Everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Erasing all contents and settings and setting up the device as a new iPhone did the trick. (It had been previously restored from a 6S backup).

Answer (score 2):

Try going into Settings > General > Reset > Reset network settings.

That will also clear out any remembered WiFi networks so you will have to re-authenticate. But I have found that doing this often fixes a variety of network-bound problems.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work.